# Find all permutations of N vectors and build every possible combination of these vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, combinations, permutation

Given are N row vectors. To each vector, I find all unique permutations of its elements (by that getting more vectors). Now I want to find all possible combinations of these vectors.

Example: Let N=3, and let the vectors be called v1, v2, v3. Using

```
unique(perms(vi),'rows');
```

I create all unique permutations to each vector. Suppose, there is 1 unique permutation for v1 (call it v1p1), 2 for v2 (v2p1, v2p2) and 4 for v3 (v3p1 ... v3p4). What I want to generate now are combined vectors:

```
[ v1p1 v2p1 v3p1 ]
[ v1p1 v2p1 v3p2 ]
[ v1p1 v2p1 v3p3 ]
[ v1p1 v2p1 v3p4 ]
[ v1p1 v2p2 v3p1 ]
[ v1p1 v2p2 v3p2 ]
[ v1p1 v2p2 v3p3 ]
[ v1p1 v2p2 v3p4 ]
```

I can do this with for-loops for a given N, but I do not know how to generalize it for the case of arbitrary N.

I have also found a way to create such a matrix with indices corresponding to the permutation number, i.e.

```
[ 1 1 1 ]
[ 1 1 2 ]
[ 1 1 3 ]
[ 1 1 4 ]
[ 1 2 1 ]
[ 1 2 2 ]
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 1 2 4 ]
```

but I don't know how to use these indices to build the vectors I want.

Comment: you can try using your indices-vector like `[1 2 4]` to take the matrix entries from a 2d matrix of `[v1p1 0 0 0, v2p1 v2p2 0 0, v3p1 v3p2 v3p3 v3p4]`

Comment: You can probably just subreference to the vector. `v=[2,4,6,8]; m= [1,1,2;3,2,4;3,3,3]; disp(v(m));`